# ajax- How to get the array in my console log?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

Im currently trying to get the response array in my console that comes from my Dropbox API. And I want to get that array so that I will display it in my JStree.. 
I try the console.log(fulltree.entries) to show the array and this is the result [console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Krt.png) I want to get that array in my console to show in my jstree

```
$(function() {
    var fullTree;
    var url = 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/delta';
    var access_token = 'My ACCESS TOKEN IN DROPBOXAPI';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: fullTree,
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json", 
        beforeSend: function(request) {
            request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + access_token);
        },
        success: function(fullTree) {
            $('#container').jstree({
                'core': {
                    "data": fullTree.entries,
                    "check_callback": true,
                },
                "plugins": ["themes", "contextmenu", "ui","icon"]
            });
            console.log(fullTree.entries);
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Not clear what you want. Can you elaborate a bit what you need. You have the array with you. Then what?

Comment: I want to show it in my jstree. because it only showing the 12 folders without the name of the folder in my dropbox

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert array to string and then use console.log().

   `console.log(JSON.stringify(fullTree.entries));`

   Hope this will help.